# Can't get my LED to flash

Tags: gpio, led

I'm trying to get started with GPIO, but I just can't get this LED to flash on and off, for some reason.

I'm using Raspbian on an old model B Pi with a 26 pin breakout board and a breadboard. The wiring is fine, the LED turns on but nothing happens when I run the code, it just stays on solid. I have a photo of the wired breadboard as well as the code. The LED IS lit, a bit hard to see as the pic was taken with a flash so you can see detail better. To be clear, the led does light up when the Pi is on.

[image: Pi and wiring]
[image: Close up]
[image: Code running in LXTerminal]
The following is the code from the tutorial that I am using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
pinNum = 8
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #numbering scheme that corresponds to breakout board and pin layout
GPIO.setup(pinNum,GPIO.OUT) #replace pinNum with whatever pin you used, this sets up that pin as an output
#set LED to flash forever
while True:
    GPIO.output(pinNum,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(pinNum,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You can add the photo by editing your question, placing your cursor where yo want the photo to appear and clicking the mountain icon and following the prompts. To rule out the obvious did you reverse the LED (they have polarity - the longer leg is positive)? Also, are you sure the ribbon cable is properly aligned? The usually have a stripe indicating pin 1 this needs to attach to the pins closest to the sd card.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I added the photo:) Also, yes I checked polarity on the led, short end (negative) goes to ground, also have the ribbon correct, red stripe at the edge of the board.

Comment: Any chance of getting a better pic it is hard to tell what pins you used on the breakout board (even when I zoom in). Also, have you tried connecting the white wire to 3.3 Volts to rule out a bad LED?

Comment: The led is fine, it lights up when the pi is powered on. I have connected the white wire to several different pins including the 3.3 and they all light up the led. The problem is not getting the led to turn on, but to make it flash (blink) when I run the python code in a terminal. When I run the code the led is supposed to flash on and off and instead it just stays on solid like it always is while the pi is turned on.

Comment: If I have time tomorrow I will set everything up with the led lit  and try to get a clearer image but the white wire went to bcm pin 8. Here is the example I'm working from: [Example:](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/morse_code/) Just gotta make that little bastard flash on and off!

Comment: Rather than trying to get other people to debug your problems you should learn to do it yourself. Here you have 3 things; code, cable and circuit. No one can solve this; you separate into steps. 1. Write sample code to set a pin (comment out one of your writes). 2. Check that this changes the pin state `gpio readall` 3. check that the state sets the actual GPIO  (multimeter helps) 4. Check if this turns LED on/off.

Comment: Have you tried running it from a script, instead of the python shell?

Comment: I actually spent several hours working by myself before reaching out. I always try very hard to figure something out before asking anyone anything, in fact most of the time I never end up reaching out at all. That often results frustration and becoming discouraged, even to the point of giving up. I thought this was a place that beginners could ask for help or guidance which is why I posted here, perhaps I was wrong. Perhaps not though as other commenters have actually tried to help. Even you did a little bit although I'm not sure which line you were suggesting I comment out.

Comment: Not looking to be handed a solution, just have what should be a really simple demo project (an led 'hello world' if you will) and it refuses to work so I was hoping someone on here might see where I've gone wrong or point me in a helpful direction after grinding by myself to no avail - if that is cool with everyone...

Comment: Hey again Steve, no haven't used a script, don't know how to do that. Bit of a noob here...:(

Comment: from the terminal window (not the shell - the $prompt ) create the blink.py file (nano blink.py). Copy and paste your code into the editor then save and exit nano (ctrl-o, enter, ctrl-x) . You should now have a blink.py file in your current directory. To run your script type python blink.py to run it.

Comment: Holy sh!t Steve. That actually worked. WTF??? Why does it not run from the terminal?? That is how the tutorial said to do it...? It is blinking on and off right now.

Comment: Also, did you see my comment below about bcm 7/8 thingy? Anyways thanks a bunch, guess I just have to do everything in a script...? Not sure why but at least the bloody thing is blinking now.

Comment: I did see your other comment (re: pin 7 and 8). I am not sure why your attempt at the shell didn't work. I am not seeing the error and can make it work from the shell, but in general multiline scripts are easier to debug and modify if you don't have to reenter them constantly.

Comment: There was no error, it just wasn't working. Weird thing is, I hadn't noticed before but the first time I'd try this after a reboot it would actually cause the led to turn OFF!? As soon as I would close the terminal the led would turn back on again and on subseqeunt tries it just stayed on solid until the next reboot. Then I tried running it line by line and found out  that the GPIO.setup function call is where things so sideways and the led turns off, also there is a warning (this channel is already in use) until terminal is closed, then the led stays on solid no matter what until next reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried your circuit and code, and it should work, However, looking closely at the photo and counting holes in the breadbaord I think the problem is that the white wire is actually connected to the last pin of the breakout board. That would be pin 7 not pin 8.

You can fix the problem in hardware or in software:

To correct the problem from hardware simply move the white wire one pin to the right (the next to last pin on the breakout board).

To fix it via software change this line:

```
pinNum = 8
```

to this:

```
pinNum = 7
```

Note: you only need to make one of the above changes not both.

Comment: Aha, good catch Steve, I noticed that myself after taking the pic. As I mentioned I had tried moving that wire to some other pins to see if they worked also (many did) and must have forgotten to move the wire back to bcm 8 before taking the pic. My bad, that muddied the waters considerably. To be clear it was in 8 for my first test and I have re-tried everything just now to confirm. Still solid on all the time:( I even tried using every pin 1 - 26... getting desperate... Thanks very much for the replies though!

Answer (score 0):

Steve showed me how to save my code to a python script and the led blinks now. Not sure why this doesn't work from running the code in the terminal, but I suppose this is officially solved. Just so strange why the tutorial would say to run the code right inside the terminal if it can't work... weird. Anyways THANK YOU STEVE!

Comment: It can work from the shell. I have a copy working, but like I said when you have a multiline script it is easier to edit and run it if you don't need to reenter it.

Comment: I may have found the problem you had in the shell. Assuming the screenshot above is what you did you needed to hit return a couple of times after the last sleep call.

Comment: Wow, that was the deal, I had to hit return one extra time. Whoops! Thanks again bud. Also, any idea why the led keeps flashing after I close the terminal? Is there a way to end the program or do I just have to reboot the pi?

Comment: ctrl-c will usually end it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. It is designed to make physical computing much easier. The documentation is great and has lots of good beginner examples.

Using `gpiozero`, your example becomes:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from signal import pause

led = LED(8)
led.blink(0.5, 0.5)

pause()   # keeps the program running so the led will blink use ctrl-c to end
```